# Update html container with Javascript - Strange issue

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have a javascript function that is fired by a javascript timer.

Every time the timer fires, I need to add an html string to a container that can accept & display html on the screen.

As more html is appended to the container, the container scrolls to the bottom.

My problem is that the html stops getting shown after a while in the div, even though **the alert is popping up** with the correct value.

Am i implementing this incorrectly or am i using the wrong control to do this?

I am using asp.net & c#.

Here is the code i am using to find and enter html into a div (message is an input parameter of the function):

```
 var lbl = document.getElementById('lblMesssage');

      lbl.innerHTML += '<div><b><span style="color: red;">Message:</span></b><br />' + message + '<hr /></div>';
      alert('message: ' + message);

      lbl.scrollTop = lbl.scrollHeight;
```

Here is the HTML for the div:

```
  <div id="lblMesssage" style="overflow: scroll; border: solid 1px #3333FF; width: 98%;
    height: 100%;">
  </div>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How much output do you get before it stops working?  Do you get the scrollbars you are expecting?

Comment: It stops workings between 5 - 10 lines, its always seems to be different. The scroll bars display when i expect them and it seems to show correctly.

Comment: Does the scrollbar size continue to change, even though no new text is appearing in the DIV? Does it work correctly if you take out the alert()?

Comment: @belugabob: once it text stops displaying, the the scroll bar size doesn't change or move anymore. the behavior doesn't change if the alert is removed. (i just added the alert make sure the messages where getting into the function)

Comment: OK, next question is - what are the values being passed in 'message' (Do they contain anything that could mess up the HTML?)